# LINQ Expression conversion issue

Tags: linq, lambda, expression-trees

I'm trying to find how to make this to work with various types.
Thanks in advance for the help!

```
public static void Main()
{
    GetKeySelector("String01");     // OK
    GetKeySelector("Date01");       // ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' cannot be used for return type 'System.String'
    GetKeySelector("Integer01");    // ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.String'
}


private static Expression<Func<Project,string>> GetKeySelector(string propertyName)

{    
   var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Project), "p");
   var property = Expression.Property(paramExpr, propertyName);  
   var finalLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Project, string>>(property, paramExpr);
   return finalLambda;
}

class Project
{
    public DateTime? Date01 {get;set;}  
    public int Integer01 {get;set;}     
    public string String01 {get;set;} 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by various types?  Like taking in a generic instead of `Project`?

Comment: Well, your func is returning string, but you're trying to return DateTime or an integer. What is the desired behavior? Do you want to convert the returned property into string before hand?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use properties of types other than `string` in an expression that produces a `string`. This is not allowed without a conversion.

One way to solve this issue would be changing the code to produce `object`s instead of `string`s, like this:

```
private static Expression<Func<Project,object>> GetKeySelector(string propertyName) {    
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Project), "p");
    var property = Expression.Property(paramExpr, propertyName); 
    var cast = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Project,object>>(cast, paramExpr);
}
```

Alternatively you could call `Convert.ToString` through an expression.

Comment: as variant call `Convert.ToString` or something like